# Simple PHP dom parser - Get text with no tag

Tags: php, parsing, dom, foreach, find

I'm trying to retrieve the game mode of a server. 
This is the code:

```
<p>
<strong>Grand Bazaar</strong>
<span class="bullet">•</span>
Rush •
<img src="src.png">
</p>
```

I'm trying to find Rush. I tried this script:

```
    foreach($html->find('p .bullet') as $e)
{
    $mode = $e->nextSibling ();
}
```

But the script just skips "Rush" and continues over to the next tag.
I'm sure you guys know what you're doing better than me.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Whenever I can't find something with this same parser, I use `preg_match`. Use it to search between `</span>` and `<img src="src.png">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your questions clearer mate... "I'm trying to retrieve the game mode of a server" <- This is irrelevant in relation with your problem for example.

The problem you're having is that "Rush" is nothing but text, it's not a sibling of .bullet as that would imply Rush being the content of a tag that's a sibling to .bullet, say

```
<span class="bullet">•</span>
<span>Rush •</span>
<img src="src.png">
```

If the structure you presented is identical all the time though, and you're using Simple HTML DOM by the looks of the code (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), then you could maybe clear the contents of the  tag first:

```
$strong = $html->find('strong'); // I think you can use prevSibling in your example
$strong->innerText = null;
```

And then just strip_tags() on the whole paragraph and get the text?